# Decide whether the series ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Determine whether the series converges or diverges
>   $${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}}$$

I was thinking I should use ratio test but I get an ugly sequence that I don't know how to evaluate. Also, the only tests we can use are comparison test, ratio test, alternating series test, divergence test and integral test and I can't seem to find one that works.

Comment: A ratio test should handle this. $\qquad$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1+5^{n+1}}{1+6^{n+1}}}{\frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}} &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+5^{n+1})(1+6^n)}{(1+5^n)(1+6^{n+1})}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(5^{-n}+5)(6^{-n}+1)}{(5^{-n}+1)(6^{-n}+6)}\\
&=\frac{(0+5)(0+1)}{(0+1)(0+6)}\\
&=\frac{5}{6}<1,
\end{align}
ratio test works and given series converges.

Answer (score 16):

$\dfrac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}\leq \dfrac{1+5^n}{6^n}\leq 2\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^n$. Now use the comparison test.